# Bigquery Storage API gRPC http status 400 from storage.googleapis.com

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, grpc, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I'm building a BigQuery Storage Client for R. Part of that involve a lot of debugging, compiling, reading code etc...

I'm trying to replicate the basic python example using `grpc_cli` to understand why my implementation is getting rejected by storage.googleapis.com while it goes through with Python. I think I understand what I am sending. I think it produces the same gRPC request but obviously not.

I'm probably still missing something cause the damn googleapis server is still returning a 400. I'm down to wireshark and sniffing the packets but if could not have to learn how to do that too, it would be great.

```
# export GRPC_TRACE=all
# export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG

unset GRPC_TRACE
export GRPC_VERBOSITY=ERROR
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="bq-storage-dev.json"

grpc_cli call bigquerystorage.googleapis.com:443 google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryRead/CreateReadSession --protofiles google/cloud/bigquery/storage/v1/storage.proto --proto_path ~/bigrquerystorage/inst/proto --channel_creds_type=gdc --json_output --binary_input --infile=~/request.bin --noremotedb --metadata=x-goog-request-params:read_session.table=projects/bigquery-public-data/datasets/usa_names/tables/usa_1910_current:x-goog-api-client:bigrquerystorage%20gl-r/4.0.3x86_64-pc-linux-gnu%20grpc/13.0.0_geeky%20gccl/0.2.0%20gargle/0.5.0
```

request.bin is the binary content of session object

```
> serialize(session, NULL)
  [1] 0a 22 70 72 6f 6a 65 63 74 73 2f 6c 61 62 6f 2d 62 72 75 6e 6f 74 72 65 6d 62 6c 61
 [29] 79 2d 32 35 33 33 31 37 12 71 18 01 32 48 70 72 6f 6a 65 63 74 73 2f 62 69 67 71 75
 [57] 65 72 79 2d 70 75 62 6c 69 63 2d 64 61 74 61 2f 64 61 74 61 73 65 74 73 2f 75 73 61
 [85] 5f 6e 61 6d 65 73 2f 74 61 62 6c 65 73 2f 75 73 61 5f 31 39 31 30 5f 63 75 72 72 65
[113] 6e 74 42 23 0a 04 6e 61 6d 65 0a 06 6e 75 6d 62 65 72 0a 05 73 74 61 74 65 12 0c 73
[141] 74 61 74 65 20 3d 20 22 57 41 22 18 01
> rawToChar(serialize(session, NULL))
[1] "\n\"projects/labo-brunotremblay-253317\022q\030\0012Hprojects/bigquery-public-data/datasets/usa_names/tables/usa_1910_currentB#\n\004name\n\006number\n\005state\022\fstate = \"WA\"\030\001"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Edit :
This would be the equivalent request.bin for Python, works fine.

```
>>> from google.cloud.bigquery_storage_v1.types import storage
>>> request_serializer=storage.CreateReadSessionRequest.serialize
>>> request = storage.CreateReadSessionRequest(None)
>>> request.parent = parent
>>> request.read_session = requested_session
>>> request.max_stream_count = 1
>>> request_serializer(request)
b'\n"projects/labo-brunotremblay-253317\x12q\x18\x012Hprojects/bigquery-public-data/datasets/usa_names/tables/usa_1910_currentB#\n\x04name\n\x06number\n\x05state\x12\x0cstate = "WA"\x18\x01'
```

Comment: After activating both traces with GRPC_TRACE=all, I think I've narrowed it down to the op sequence in call.cc. So now it works but I do not understand why. This is fine.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out how to build the BigQuery Storage R Client.
https://github.com/meztez/bigrquerystorage

Using grpc_cli to acces BigQuery Storage API was the wrong way to do it.

I needed to generated the boilerplate code using protoc then to build the client from the generated code.

After that it was a matter of mapping protobuf field to R input and adding the right credentials builder.